# Why does my multimeter capacitance measure not show up until I lift the probe?

Tags: capacitor

I am testing a simple homemade parallel capacitor with tin foil. My plate distance is about an inch. the plates are hooked up to a battery. When I touch my multimeter probe to the plates nothing shows up. However, when I pull one of the probes away, an nF reading will show up for a brief moment. I have to continually touch and lift the probe to get the nf reading. Why do I have to lift the probe to get the reading? What is going on?

Comment: Disconnect the battery and see how it goes.

Comment: *plate distance is about an inch*. That seems very large. Have you calculated the capacitance using the standard formula ? Is the calculated value within the range of the multimeter ?

Answer (score 4):

To test a capacitor the test meter will apply a voltage or current to the DUT (device under test) and measure the response. For example, if it applies a constant current it can measure how long it takes to go from one voltage to another and work out the C value from \$ i = C \frac {dV}{dt} \$.

If you've left your battery connected then it will sink the current (if you don't destroy it) and your reading will be nonsense.

In general you can't measure the value of components in live circuits.